# Villa-Lobos Etude No. 2 - Arpeggio part - how to play the consecutive bass strings

Tags: technique, classical-guitar, arpeggios

I'm a beginner classical guitarist (I have been playing the instrument itself for a while) in the middle of learning Villa-Lobos Etude No. 2.

I just wanted to know how I should be playing the arpeggio part - I see two bass notes, which I have been playing with (pi) then starting with the p on the treble notes.

But perhaps I should be playing the two bass notes with (p)?

Any tip would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please post a copy of that part for us.

Comment: I don't know the piece, but trying to find a video where you can see how it's being played (like this one perhaps https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ldhh6FrM4H4) can be quite helpful.

Answer (score 1):

There are several variations but try this one. After some practice it should flow easily. "-" sign means "ligado" or hammer-on/off

5.p - 4.p 3.i 2.m 1.a

now comes the jump to A on 2nd string played with i

then m, a - , i, m, now jump back and play with "a" finger all 4 remaining notes,
like sliding with a finger.

Use the same technique on all arpeggios with slight variations.
The tricky part in this etude is left hand fingering. 
Let me know if you get stuck.
Good luck.